# The resource from “http://localhost:3000/public/static/” was blocked due to MIME type (“text/html”) mismatch (X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff)

Tags: javascript, express

[image: The project directory]

I keep getting the error in the title every time I attempt to host the server with nodemon.
Here is the code in the javascript file:

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path')
const app = express() // initialising express and saving as app
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/static/views')) // setting views directory to the views folder

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))

// redering home page
app.get('/', (req, res) => {
    res.render('home.ejs')
})

// listening for requests on localhost 3000
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is live!')
})
```

The code which I have shared above is in the index.js file. The home.ejs file has the following script tag:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/public/static/timer.js" defer></script>
```

The timer.js file is empty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'static')))
```

This line of code adds 'static' to the end of the directory where the index.js file is stored and makes the resulting directory static. It does not preserve the existing directory structure. So the script statement should be something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="timer.js" defer></script>
```